# "long is not defined" error on express js get method

Tags: express

I tried these three type of  url methods

```
<a href="/delete?id={{ this._id }}">Delete</a>
<a href="/delete/{{ this._id }}">Delete</a>
<a href="/delete:{{ this._id }}">Delete</a>
```

My get function

```
router.get('/delete', function(req, res, next) { 
 var id = req.params.id;
 console.log(id);
 console;long('asdasd');
 mongo.connect(url, function(err, db) {
assert.equal(null, err);
db.collection('user-data').deleteOne({"_id": objectId(id)}, function(err,       result) {
  assert.equal(null, err);
  console.log('Item deleted');
  db.close();
});
});
});
```

Then I tried this one also

```
 router.get('/delete:id', function(req, res, next)
```

Im getting `Long is not defined`

I am new to express..what is that issue..help me to fix it

Answer (score 1):

Each message has `message_id` it's in header:

`Message-ID: <xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@email.com>`

For the reply email also contains in header:

`References: <xxx1@mail.com> <xxx2@mail.com>
 <xxx3@mail.gmail.com> ....
In-Reply-To: <xxx1@mail.gmail.com>`

Where `References` is the list with all emails related and `In-Reply-To` is the id of original message and this email is reply to that email.

Comment: But can we get the reply message content?

Comment: @Jana yes, you need to find email by ID provided in `In-Reply-To` header.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23411260/retrieve-a-single-email-from-imap-by-message-id

but if it doesn't work probably you will need to get headers for all emails in inbox and find correct one in that list

Comment: @Alexandra I understood ..But Im new to IMAP..so couldn't get that coding way..have you tried it before?..can you show me the code?